# Access UITableView Cell label text and use it in a method

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to access the text in a uitablecell I have created, and then add that text to a database. There is a button beside each cell, and when the user taps the button, it is supposed to add the cell label text into a database, but i could not figure out how. I would appreciate any help.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let cellDataParse: PFObject = self.dataparse.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellDataParse.objectForKey("GroupName")! as? String
    let button: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 8, width: 46, height: 30)
    button.setTitle("Join", forState: .Normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    cell.addSubview(button)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "JoinGroupAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


     func JoinGroupAction () {
        var usergroups = PFObject(className: "UserGroups")
        usergroups["Groups"] = cell.textLabel!.text!
            usergroups.save()


        var usergrouprelations: PFRelation = PFUser.currentUser()!.relationForKey("MyGroups")
        usergrouprelations.addObject(usergroups)
        PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                println("Completed")

            } else {

                println("Not Completed")
            }
        })



    }


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a subclass of a UBButton with a property to store the value of the text and then get it out of the sender for your action..

```
class MyButton : UIButton {

    var myText : String

}
```

The take the action for the button out of the cell and add it as a class method.

Then make sure you make the button in your table this new class and inside your cell assign the text label text to the button's myText property.

```
func myButtonTouchedAction(sender: MyButton) {

    let textFromCell = sender.myText

}
```

Also make sure to add a ":" to the end of the action where you define the button in the cell otherwise you won't be able to use sender in the function.

As pointed out while I was writing this, you can use the indexPath, though I think it's more work, you can use the UIButton's default tag property to store the current indexPath (thought it won't work if you're using multiple table sections unless your buttons are only needed in one section), then re grab your data based on the value sent along in the button's tag.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule its a bad idea to use views to hold data. You should create an array to hold your cell data, save the data into that array, and then fetch values from the array when the user taps a button.

What part of this are you having trouble doing? Is your `JoinGroupAction` method supposed to be the method that gets called when the user taps a button in your table view? How is that connected? Is it wired up as an IBAction? If so, it should have the IBAction tag. Also you should use the form of IBAction that takes a sender parameter.

Comment: I am using the function to add the table cell label text into the database. I have hooked it up to the button using the add target method. The function works fine when I hardcode a string into the [groups] object, but I want the string value to be whatever the label of the cell that the user tapped is.

Comment: As I said in my answer, it is a bad idea to fetch values from the cell labels. You should use the approach @Rasputin outlined in his code to figure out which cell was tapped, then look up the data from an array that you have set up to store the values. Cell contents are volatile and can change out from under you. It's also a violation of the MVC design pattern. You are using your view objects as model objects. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. One, I would not put the `JoinGroupAction` func inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath()`. Second, what you'll need to do is change the function slightly so that it gets the cell at the `indexPath` for which the button was tapped, and then you will be able to pull the text information out of the cell to upload it to Parse.

Assuming you have an `IBAction` for your button, you should do something like this:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    if let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint) as? NSIndexPath {

   let cell = cellForRowAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
   let parseText = cell.textLabel?.text
   //upload your info to Parse
   }
}
```

OR you could use `objectAtIndexPath` since you're using Parse.

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    if let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint) as? NSIndexPath {

   let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
   let parseText = object.valueForKey("desiredText")
   //upload your info to Parse
   }
}
```

Comment: Good catch on not putting JoinGroupAction inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. I missed that.

Comment: Alright, thank you, but could you please show me what you mean in code, I don't exactly understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add sender to JoinGroupAction,

```
func JoinGroupAction (sender: UIButton) {
    var usergroups = PFObject(className: "UserGroups")
    usergroups["Groups"] = cell.textLabel!.text!
        usergroups.save()


    var usergrouprelations: PFRelation = PFUser.currentUser()!.relationForKey("MyGroups")
    usergrouprelations.addObject(usergroups)
    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            println("Completed")

        } else {

            println("Not Completed")
        }
    })
}
```

Then add this inside JoinGroupAction to get cell text,

```
var btnPos: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)!
UITableViewCell cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
String cellLabelToDatabase = cell.textLabel?.text
```